# Cleanest and fastest way to filter subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using an array and a `for` loop in PHP and it works well without any problem, but I want to improve the performance and speed of the script.

This is my script (PHP) :

```
$data=[1,2,3,4=>[1,2]];
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if(is_array($data[$i]){
        //do something
    }
}
```

As you can see it will check the whole array to detect if array has sub array or not and the thing which I want to know is - is there anyway to filter this array and send the filtered sub arrays to `foreach`? I mean just use elements which have a sub array, like `$data[4]` which has this sub array : `[1,2]` (which I'm currently checking by using `is_array` in `if(is_array($data[$i]){`).

If the array was like this: `$data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10=>[1,2],11,12,13,14,15=>[1,2]];` it would take more time to find only 2 useful elements (10 and 15) and others (1 to 9 and 11 to 14) are useless, I want to skip them before I use them on `foreach`.

I'm not looking for a way to do it manually inside my existing loop, I'm looking for a built-in function which would be optimized for speed and performance.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `array_filter($data, "is_array");`?

Comment: _"i want to skip them before i use them"_ and _"and if you gonna say that i can use other variable and save the arrays which has sub array on other variable with same foreach code or something like that sadly i don't need it"_ are not compatible demands. You either extract only the elements you need or you iterate the whole array every time you need to use these.

Comment: @El_Vanja i mean with a filter function or something which is PHP already has and its works fast like other default PHP functions something like trim()

Comment: @FelippeDuarte exactly thanks a lot. that't what i was looking for.

Comment: Aside: Counting your array upon each iteration is wasteful.  Count it upfront.  Or just use foreach for array loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all elements that is an array:

```
$data = array_filter($data, "is_array");
```

Get all elements that is **not** an array:

```
$data = array_filter($data, fn($e) => !is_array($e));
```